# trouble bootstrapping data with Grails Audit-Trail plugin installed

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, bootstrapping, audit-trail

I am working on a Grails 2.3.4 application.  I am adding the [Audit-Trail Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/audit-trail) v2.0.3 to our project because we have a requirement to track all create and modify times and users to help debug problems that might arise.  I have sucessfully installed the plugin and everything works EXCEPT that we cannot bootstrap data in the development enviornment anymore.

This is in our Config.groovy:

```
plugin {

    audittrail {
        createdBy.field = "createUser"
        createdBy.type = "java.lang.String"
        createdDate.field = "createDate"

        editedBy.field = "updateUser"
        editedBy.type = "java.lang.String"
        editedDate.field = "updateDate"
        /*
            This closure returns the value of the user for the plugin.
         */
        currentUserClosure = { ctx ->
            ctx.userServiceProxy.getUserToken()

        }
    }
```

Here is the UserService
    package com.perceptivecloud.frg.datadefinition

```
/**
* Service class to help the Audit-Trail plugin get userId information.
*
* TODO:This will need to be revisited when  real Authorization is implemented.
*/
class UserService {
/*
    force a new instance of the service per session.
    see http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/services.html#scopedServices for details
 */
static scope = "session"

   String userToken

    void setUserToken(String userId) {
        userToken = userId
    }

    String getUserToken() {
        userToken
    }

}
```

The proxy service is defined in resources.groovy:

```
userServiceProxy(ScopedProxyFactoryBean) {
    targetBeanName = 'userService'
    proxyTargetClass = true
}
```

Our Domain class looks like:

```
@AuditStamp
class MyDomainClass {
    String name

    static constraints = {
        name nullable: false
    }

}
```

Our BootStrap.groovy looks like:

```
def userServiceProxy
...
development {
    userServiceProxy.setUserToken("bootstrap")

    def claims = new MyDomainClass(name: 'Submit claim')
    claims.save(flush: true)
}
```

When I start up the app, I get a stack trace that looks like:

```
| Error 2014-03-13 13:10:48,963 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
Message: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    Line | Method
->>   41 | doCall                       in BootStrap$_closure1_closure2_closure4
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    321 | execute                      in grails.util.Environment$EnvironmentBlockEvaluator
|    302 | executeForEnvironment . . .  in grails.util.Environment
|    277 | executeForCurrentEnvironment in     ''
|    262 | run . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker                    in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run                          in java.lang.Thread
```

When I tried to create a session in bootstrap like so:

```
development {
    WebUtils.storeGrailsWebRequest(new GrailsWebRequest(new GrailsMockHttpServletRequest(),
        new GrailsMockHttpServletResponse(), (ServletContext)servletContext))
WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest().applicationContext.getBean('userServiceProxy')
    .setUserToken("userToken")

    def claims = new MyDomainClass(name: 'Submit claim')
    claims.save(flush: true)
}
```

I got the following error.

```
| Error 2014-03-13 12:50:34,179 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hibernate.AssertionFailure  - an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session)
Message: null id in MyDomainClass entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
    Line | Method
->>  112 | doCall                       in Config$_run_closure2_closure7_closure11_closure12
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     67 | currentUserId                in grails.plugin.audittrail.AuditTrailHelper
|     45 | doCall . . . . . . . . . . . in grails.plugin.audittrail.AuditTrailInterceptor$_onSave_closure1
|     37 | onSave                       in grails.plugin.audittrail.AuditTrailInterceptor
|     46 | doCall . . . . . . . . . . . in BootStrap$_closure1_closure2_closure4
|    321 | execute                      in grails.util.Environment$EnvironmentBlockEvaluator
|    302 | executeForEnvironment . . .  in grails.util.Environment
|    277 | executeForCurrentEnvironment in     ''
|    262 | run . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker                    in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run                          in java.lang.Thread
```

From what these messages tell me, somehow I need to be able to save the objects within a request or session context, and I do not know how to do that.

At absolute minimum, the problem I am trying to solve is making sure there is consistent data in the database every time the development environment is fired up while using the Audit-Trail plugin.

Comment: What about Audit Logging Plugin?

Comment: The audit logging plugin did not fit our requirements, but I did look at it.  The Audit Logging Plugin manages a seperate table will full change tracking.  What was requested was just a quick ability to see who last touched the object and when.  My manager and I did discuss the Audit Logging Plugin.

Comment: It does not look like I can post an answer to my own question, but to follow up, the root problem is that there is no web session in bootstrap.  I worked around this by no longer scoping the service to session, and instead storing the user directly into the web session as in "WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest().session['userToken'] = userId"  Then when I go to retrieve the user, I wrap this call in a try-catch(IllegalStateException e) and return a value for the bootstrap user.  NOT elegant at all, but got the job done.

Comment: This is very simple to do if you want to avoid a plugin and don't mind using a base class for extension. Grails already automatically adds the dateCreated and lastUpdated fields for you if they are in your domain class. All that is left if to add a modifiedBy field and pull this information from the correct place upon insert and update. For instance with Spring Security you can get the current logged in user from the context. You can put all of this in a base class in src/groovy and extend in your domain classes. I can share source if you are interested in building outside of a plugin.